ApiPlatform generates invalid IRI (without ID) when using State Provider
I have a User entity in API Platform and created a custom operation to return information about the currently logged-in user, using a state provider.
ApiResource tag:
#[ApiResource(
  operations: [
    new Get(
      uriTemplate: '/user',
      normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['user:read']],
      security: self::SECURITY_GET,
      provider: UserStateProvider::class
    )
]

UserStateProvider:
class UserStateProvider implements ProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        private readonly Security $security,
    ) {}

    public function provide(Operation $operation, array $uriVariables = [], array $context = []): object|array|null
    {
        return $this->security->getUser();
    }
}

The problem: This endpoint returns an IRI without an ID, which looks like this:
"@context": "/api/contexts/User",
"@id": "/api/user",
"@type": "User",

I attempted to fetch the user from the repository within UserStateProvider, but it did not resolve the issue:
$user = $this->security->getUser();
return $user ? $this->userRepository->find($user->getId()) : null;

User Resource:


#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: '`users`')]
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new Get(
            uriTemplate: '/user',
            normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['user:read']],
            security: self::SECURITY_GET,
            provider: UserStateProvider::class
        ),
        new Get(
            uriTemplate: '/user/data',
            normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['user:read', 'userdata:read']],
            security: self::SECURITY_GET,
            provider: UserStateProvider::class
        ),
        new Post(
            uriTemplate: '/user/register/',
            controller: RegisterController::class,
            normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['user:read', 'userdata:read']],
        ),
    ],
    denormalizationContext: [
        'groups' => [ 'user:write' ]
    ]
)]
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface, SubscribeEntity
{
    const SECURITY_GET = "is_granted('ROLE_USER')";

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    #[ApiProperty(identifier: true)]
    #[Groups(['user:read'])]
    private ?int $id = null;


    /**
     * @var list<string> The user roles
     */
    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Groups(['user:read'])]
    private array $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     */
    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Groups(['user:write'])]
    private ?string $password = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, unique: true)]
    #[Groups(['user:read', 'user:write', 'channel:read', 'purchasedTicket:readUser'])]
    private ?string $nickname = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Groups(['userdata:read'])]
    private ?\DateTimeImmutable $createdAt = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?\DateTimeImmutable $updatedAt = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, unique: true)]
    #[Groups(['user:read', 'user:write', 'purchasedTicket:readUser'])]
    #[Email]
    private ?string $email = null;

    #[ORM\OneToOne(mappedBy: 'user', cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    #[Groups(['userdata:read', 'user:write'])]
    private ?UserData $userData = null;

    /**
     * @var Collection<int, UserChange>
     */
    #[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: UserChange::class, mappedBy: 'user')]
    private Collection $userChanges;

    /**
     * @var Collection<int, Channel>
     */
    #[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: Channel::class, mappedBy: 'user')]
    private Collection $channels;

    /**
     * @var Collection<int, Channel>
     */
    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Channel::class, mappedBy: 'moderators')]
    private Collection $moderateChannels;

    /**
     * @var Collection<int, Comment>
     */
    #[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: Comment::class, mappedBy: 'author')]
    private Collection $comments;

    /**
     * @var Collection<int, PurchasedTicket>
     */
    #[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: PurchasedTicket::class, mappedBy: 'user')]
    private Collection $purchasedTickets;

    /**
     * @var Collection<int, CartItem>
     */
    #[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: CartItem::class, mappedBy: 'user')]
    private Collection $cartItems;

    /**
     * @var Collection<int, Subscription>
     */
    #[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: Subscription::class, mappedBy: 'user')]
    private Collection $subscriptions;

    /**
     * @var Collection<int, PurchasedVideoContent>
     */
    #[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: PurchasedVideoContent::class, mappedBy: 'user')]
    private Collection $purchasedVideoContents;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTimeImmutable();
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTimeImmutable();
        $this->userChanges = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->channels = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->moderateChannels = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->comments = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->purchasedTickets = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->cartItems = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->subscriptions = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->purchasedVideoContents = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUserIdentifier(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     *
     * @return list<string>
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    /**
     * @param list<string> $roles
     */
    public function setRoles(array $roles): static
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): static
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials(): void
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    public function getNickname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nickname;
    }

    public function setNickname(string $nickname): static
    {
        $this->nickname = $nickname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeImmutable
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeImmutable $createdAt): static
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeImmutable
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt(\DateTimeImmutable $updatedAt): static
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): static
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUserData(): ?UserData
    {
        return $this->userData;
    }

    public function setUserData(UserData $userData): static
    {
        // set the owning side of the relation if necessary
        if ($userData->getUser() !== $this) {
            $userData->setUser($this);
        }

        $this->userData = $userData;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, UserChange>
     */
    public function getUserChanges(): Collection
    {
        return $this->userChanges;
    }

    public function addUserChange(UserChange $userChange): static
    {
        if (!$this->userChanges->contains($userChange)) {
            $this->userChanges->add($userChange);
            $userChange->setUser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeUserChange(UserChange $userChange): static
    {
        if ($this->userChanges->removeElement($userChange)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($userChange->getUser() === $this) {
                $userChange->setUser(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Channel>
     */
    public function getChannels(): Collection
    {
        return $this->channels;
    }

    public function addChannel(Channel $channel): static
    {
        if (!$this->channels->contains($channel)) {
            $this->channels->add($channel);
            $channel->setUser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeChannel(Channel $channel): static
    {
        if ($this->channels->removeElement($channel)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($channel->getUser() === $this) {
                $channel->setUser(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Channel>
     */
    public function getModerateChannels(): Collection
    {
        return $this->moderateChannels;
    }

    public function addModerateChannel(Channel $moderateChannel): static
    {
        if (!$this->moderateChannels->contains($moderateChannel)) {
            $this->moderateChannels->add($moderateChannel);
            $moderateChannel->addModerator($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeModerateChannel(Channel $moderateChannel): static
    {
        if ($this->moderateChannels->removeElement($moderateChannel)) {
            $moderateChannel->removeModerator($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Comment>
     */
    public function getComments(): Collection
    {
        return $this->comments;
    }

    public function addComment(Comment $comment): static
    {
        if (!$this->comments->contains($comment)) {
            $this->comments->add($comment);
            $comment->setAuthor($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeComment(Comment $comment): static
    {
        if ($this->comments->removeElement($comment)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($comment->getAuthor() === $this) {
                $comment->setAuthor(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, PurchasedTicket>
     */
    public function getPurchasedTickets(): Collection
    {
        return $this->purchasedTickets;
    }

    public function addPurchasedTicket(PurchasedTicket $purchasedTicket): static
    {
        if (!$this->purchasedTickets->contains($purchasedTicket)) {
            $this->purchasedTickets->add($purchasedTicket);
            $purchasedTicket->setUser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removePurchasedTicket(PurchasedTicket $purchasedTicket): static
    {
        if ($this->purchasedTickets->removeElement($purchasedTicket)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($purchasedTicket->getUser() === $this) {
                $purchasedTicket->setUser(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, CartItem>
     */
    public function getCartItems(): Collection
    {
        return $this->cartItems;
    }

    public function addCartItem(CartItem $cartItem): static
    {
        if (!$this->cartItems->contains($cartItem)) {
            $this->cartItems->add($cartItem);
            $cartItem->setUser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCartItem(CartItem $cartItem): static
    {
        if ($this->cartItems->removeElement($cartItem)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($cartItem->getUser() === $this) {
                $cartItem->setUser(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->getNickname();
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Subscription>
     */
    public function getSubscriptions(): Collection
    {
        return $this->subscriptions;
    }

    public function addSubscription(Subscription $subscription): static
    {
        if (!$this->subscriptions->contains($subscription)) {
            $this->subscriptions->add($subscription);
            $subscription->setUser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeSubscription(Subscription $subscription): static
    {
        if ($this->subscriptions->removeElement($subscription)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($subscription->getUser() === $this) {
                $subscription->setUser(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, PurchasedVideoContent>
     */
    public function getPurchasedVideoContents(): Collection
    {
        return $this->purchasedVideoContents;
    }

    public function addPurchasedVideoContent(PurchasedVideoContent $purchasedVideoContent): static
    {
        if (!$this->purchasedVideoContents->contains($purchasedVideoContent)) {
            $this->purchasedVideoContents->add($purchasedVideoContent);
            $purchasedVideoContent->setUser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removePurchasedVideoContent(PurchasedVideoContent $purchasedVideoContent): static
    {
        if ($this->purchasedVideoContents->removeElement($purchasedVideoContent)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($purchasedVideoContent->getUser() === $this) {
                $purchasedVideoContent->setUser(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}




Do you have an $id in your User entity with the proper user:read group ?

@DylanKAS Yes. And even if I remove this, effect is same
#[Groups(['user:read'])]  private ?int $id = null;

Have you added the #[ApiProperty(identifier: true)] attribute on your id property?

Add the user resource please.

@COil I just added this tag, but it's not affected.
I also added the user resorce to the question.
